# Symfony 3 Doctrine INDEX BY foreign key

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine-orm, symfony

Why this is working:

```
$query = $this->_em->createQuery(
            'SELECT ua.id, ua.correct, (ua.user) as user_id
            FROM AppBundle:UserAnswer ua
            INDEX BY ua.id'
        );
```

However when I am trying to index by related entity User, it's not working anymore:

```
$query = $this->_em->createQuery(
            'SELECT ua
            FROM AppBundle:UserAnswer ua
            INDEX BY ua.user'
        );
```

Got error:

```
[2/2] QueryException: [Semantical Error] line 0, col 83 near 'user': Error: Invalid PathExpression. Must be a StateFieldPathExpression.   +

[1/2] QueryException: SELECT ua
FROM AppBundle:UserAnswer ua
INDEX BY ua.user   +
```

Changing to:

```
$query = $this->_em->createQuery(
            'SELECT ua.id, ua.correct, (ua.user) as user_id
            FROM AppBundle:UserAnswer ua
            INDEX BY (ua.user)'
        );
```

Throws an error:

```
[2/2] QueryException: [Syntax Error] line 0, col 126: Error: Expected end of string, got '('   +
[1/2] QueryException: SELECT ua.id, ua.correct, (ua.user) as user_id
FROM AppBundle:UserAnswer ua
INDEX BY IDENTITY (ua.user)   +
```

How can I index result array with keys as foreign key ?